# Explicit formula of exponential of companion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential, companion-matrices

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix} a_k & a_{k-1} & a_{k-2} & \cdots & a_2 & a_1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots &\\0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ be a $k \times k$ matrix of {$a_k$} on a commutative ring. Find the explicit expression of the last row of $A^n$ in terms of {$a_k$}, where $k\le n$.

Comment: if $n\le k$, it is quite easy

Comment: Yeah, let’s just consider when n is large.

Comment: If we know the last row of $A^n$ for $n \leq k$ then we can use the characteristic polynomial to find the last row for $n \geq k$. The characteristic polynomial: $x^k-a_kx^{k-1}-a_{k-1}x^{k-2}-\text{...}-a_1$

Comment: @Lozenges can you be more specific? If you refer to some characteristic polynomial based on idea of eigen values, it's not always possible to find eigen values on a ring.

Comment: You can extend the scalars to use the roots of the  the characteristic polynomial, compute the powers and end with a matrix defined over the ring you started. But maybe it's too much technology for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather a lengthy comment but I want to point out this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/256638/82672)  and these two articles pointed out there

- [The combinatorial power of the companion matrix](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379595901639)
- [SUMS OF FIBONACCI NUMBERS BY MATRIX METHODS](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/22-3/er.pdf)

I hope they will be useful.

Comment: I think the first article is the answer. Thanks!

Comment: There's something astonishingly called combinatorial matrix theory, that will give this result easily...

Comment: I'm happy it was useful :)

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it's easy. Let $n$ be an explicit integer. You divide $x^n$ by $p(x)=x^k-a_kx^{k-1}-\cdots$ and you keep the remainder which is in the form $r=u_1x^{k-1}+u_2x^{k-2}+\cdots$. We can do that because the polynomials are unitary. The required row is $[u_1,u_2,\cdots]$.

Practically, the calculation is quasi unfeasible if you keep the parameters $(a_i)$ as they are. On the contrary, it works very well if you give explicit values to the $(a_i)$ and if you use a computer (of course you have to program the $2$ operations of the ring).

Comment: didn't understand your answer for the first part. for the second part, if I can use a computer with explicit numbers, I can directly perform matrix multiplication.